# how to check if the date is in a specific format or not using typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

Is there any way to test the date formats.

I have tried below method

```
let newdate = new Date(myStringDate);
Date.parse(myStringDate)
result = `${newdate.getDate()}/${newdate.getMonth() + 1}/${newdate.getFullYear()}`
```

Here i will get result in dd/MM/yyyy format.
And now i need to check the format is valid or not. Please look into this and provide me a suitable way to check the format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> provide me a suitable way to check the format.

Here is an example using `moment`:

```
export namespace Dates {
  export const dateFormats = {
    dateTimeFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm',
    dateOnlyFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    monthYearFormat: 'MM/YYYY',
    isoFormat: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS ', // Corresponds to '2016-01-04T13:00:00Z'
  }

  export function toDate(value: string,
    /**
     * The default has *all* the formats
     *  - This is because strict date type validations
     *  - are done by passing in explicit limited sets.
     **/
    formats = [
      dateFormats.dateTimeFormat,
      dateFormats.dateOnlyFormat,
      dateFormats.isoFormat,
      dateFormats.monthYearFormat,
    ]
  ): { valid: boolean, date: Date | null } {
    if (!value || !value.trim().length) {
      return { valid: true, date: null };
    }
    let trimmed = value.trim();
    if (!formats.some(format => format.length == trimmed.length)) {
      return { valid: false, date: null };
    }
    // http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-formats/
    let date = moment(value, formats, true);
    if (!date.isValid()) {
      return { valid: false, date: null };
    }
    return { valid: true, date: date.toDate() };
  }
}
```

Feel free to change the date formats as needed

Answer (score 0):

The cheapest way to implement is to use a regular expression to check the returned format

Here is the regular expression

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^((([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))|([1-9]))/((1[0-2])|([1-9]))/[0-9]{4}$');
```

The above pattern will check for following formats

- 1/1/1991
- 1/12/1991
- 30/1/1991
- 30/12/1991

**Added bonus**
The regular expression can also check for incorrect dates like having 32 as a date or 0 in the month and even month greater than 12.